# Waiting For Network Config and Purged Network Manager in 12.04

Tags: networking

I am very new to Ubuntu and I love it dearly, however recently I had an error pop up which said:

'E:Encountered a section with no Package: header, E:Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/in.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise-updates_multiverse_binary-i386_Packages, E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.'

A few weeks later I lost my wi-fi connection.

I ended up purging software manager and this message disappeared but without network manager everything went down hill. I can't reinstall it as I have no internet connection on my lap top. Also another error appeared in its place it is a red triangle with an exclamation mark.

Now also an error returned "waiting for network configuration, which causes a very slow boot.

I have tried all sorts of commands and nothing works, I have been researching all these problems for a week and trying different things, making the problem larger than I started with. Network manager comes back with all sorts of massages, like access denied. I am freaking out that I completely stuffed the system up. I have copies of all the commands I have tried and the responses from the terminal.

Would anyone be willing to help me please?

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless card from the terminal command: lspci -nn |  grep 0280

Comment: I was able to enter the command up to lspci -nn but do not know wht the net sign is or how to apply on my key board, however, I got a reply and it seems that the card is PRO/Wireless 3945ABG (Golan). Does this sound right?

Comment: Please see my answer. The symbol was the pipe symbol | which is on the right side of my US keyboard on the same key with \. You have, however, provided the needed information.

Answer (score 0):

The wireless device 3945ABG has a driver and firmware that are built-in to all recent Ubuntu versions. Confirm that the hardware met the driver and created a wireless interface, ideally wlan0:

```
iwconfig
```

Also confirm that Network Manager is not running suggesting that you actually only deleted the desktop icon:

```
ps aux | grep -i network
```

If you see an entry for 'network-manager' then only the icon is missing; try to restore it temporarily with:

```
nm-applet &
```

If Network Manager doesn't appear as a running process, then do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces
```

If gksudo isn't installed and, obviously, you have no way to get it easily, use 'sudo' instead. Amend the file that opens to something like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
wpa-ssid <your_network>
wpa-psk <your_wpa_password>
```

Proofread carefully, save and close gedit. Reboot. Are you connected? Check:

```
 ping -c3 www.google.com
```

If you get ping returns, you are connected. If this is a stay-at-home computer that doesn't need to connect to different networks at the cyber cafe, you really needn't reinstall Network Manager. If you do need it, reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall network-manager
```

Then edit /etc/network/interfaces as above and delete the wlan0 stanza.

If you are having trouble, look for clues:

```
sudo ifdown wlan0 && sudo ifup -vv wlan0
```

'-vv' will produce output that will help us see what or where it's not connecting.

Comment: so after typing the first command suggested I got:

Comment: sorry, I got: wlan0 IEEE 802.11abg ESSID:off/any Mode:Managed Access Point: Not-Associated Tx-Power=off Power Management:on, lo no wireless extensions, eth0 no wireless extensions

Comment: You have a workable wireless interface wlan0. Excellent. I suggest you now proceed with the next steps above.

Comment: Hi again I tried what you suggested and did not get online, though I have not tried checking the ping. Here are the results which I do not understand

Comment: ps aux | grep -i network 
admin     1603  0.0  0.3  35032  3228 ?        Sl   11:06   0:00 /usr/lib/glib-networking/glib-pacrunner 
admin     2171  1.2  3.7 139472 38268 ?        Sl   11:20   
admin     2288  0.0  0.0   4392   816 pts/0    S+   11:26   0:00 grep --color=auto -i network 
nm-applet & 
[1] 2311 
admin@dtnb002:~$ The program 'nm-applet' can be found in the following packages: 
 * network-manager-gnome 
 * mythbuntu-diskless-client 
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package> [1]+  Exit 127                nm-applet 

sudo gedit /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: tried ping -3 www.google.com 
ping: invalid option -- '3' 
Usage: ping [-LRUbdfnqrvVaAD] [-c count] [-i interval] [-w deadline] 
            [-p pattern] [-s packetsize] [-t ttl] [-I interface] 
            [-M pmtudisc-hint] [-m mark] [-S sndbuf] 
            [-T tstamp-options] [-Q tos] [hop1 ...] destination

Comment: It is: ping -c3 www.google.com ...with a -c in front of the 3. It appears that NM is not installed. So far, so good. Please try ping again.

Comment: Hello Chili, the response I get is unknown host www.google.com

Comment: Please see my edit.